# How to merge two Tables and Add the amount at the same time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel tables with the amount of times we have a product and an identifier for said product. I know table A has all product-identifiers we have, but Table B has significantly less so its not exactly the same order. Is there a formula that can add the amounts for me or atleast write the amounts from table B to the corresponding rows of table A

Example:

Table A

A 10

B 10

C 10

D 10

E 10

Table B

A 10

C 10

E 10

Expected Result

A 20

B 10

C 20

D 10

E 20

Comment: have you looked into SUMIF or XLOOKUP/VLOOKUP?

Comment: I tried both but neither seems to work since the identifiers are not in the same order.  Atleast thats what I think the problem is.

Comment: You should give better example with your data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See screenshot for reference. You could use SUMPRODUCT like this:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=A10)*$B$2:$B$5)+SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$4=A10)*$E$2:$E$4)`
[image]